# How to reset notifications settings for ios app

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, badge

I want to enable my app to update `applicationIconBadgeNumber`.
For this I use:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Badge, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
...
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = someNumber
```

And all works fine. 
But now I want that user will have an option to turn off/on this notifications **inside my app**, not in iOS settings.

I've tried to use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()` but is doesn't work in my case.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't affect the permissions that have been granted to your app; once the user has responded to the initial permissions request they can only be changed in settings. You *can* simply not use the permissions you have; if you have a setting in your app not to badge, for example, simply don't set the badge value even though you have permission to do so.

Comment: Thx. You mean that I can do this, but settings in my menu and in ios menu will be different? That's not good...

Comment: That's how it will be. You are really talking about two slightly different things. Permissions and an app setting. The user grants you permissions. What do you with those permissions are a setting. I understand that the difference is subtle and your users may not understand, so maybe you should just provide a button that opens your apps settings where the user can change the assigned permissions

Comment: @Paulw11, maybe that is a good idea. And how can I open settings for my app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Settings Bundle and accordingly mention UI components to on/off inside your app.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html